# React native FlatList, how to create static cells directly on the flatlist?

Tags: uitableview, react-native, datasource, react-native-flatlist

I have been using `FlatList` for a while using the basic setup containing the props: `data`, `renderItem,`keyExtractor`etc. But what if I want to skip specifying the`data`prop and the`renderItem` prop, and instead add my cells directly onto the FlatList. For example a settings page. Something like this as pseudocode:

```
<FlatList>
    <ListCell>
        <MyCustomView/>
    </ListCell>

    <ListCell>
        <SomeOtherCustomView/>
    </ListCell>
</FlatList>
```

Comment: I don't think you'd benefit very much from a FlatList in this scenario. You're better off just wrapping your cells in a `<View>`. FlatList is good where you're displaying dozens to hundreds of dynamic items and want efficient cell re-use.

Comment: @Snowman Good point snowman

Comment: @snowman could you please post as an answer so this can be finalised. Your point sounds 100% logical and absolutely takes away the need for what I'm asking for.

Comment: Ok, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you'd benefit very much from a FlatList in this scenario. You're better off just wrapping your cells in a `<View>`. FlatList is good where you're displaying dozens to hundreds of dynamic items and want efficient cell re-use.

*[Re-iterating comment as answer]*

Comment: Absolutely makes sense. My mind is still handcuffed to objective-c.

Comment: FlatList allows the user to scroll, a simple View won't do that

Comment: ....what?  Why would you not implement a FlatList that accomplishes the same exact thing and makes it very easy to add new things to the list in the future if needed? Is FlatList that much of a performance hit that you shouldn't develop with the future in mind?

The view doesn't let you scroll.